# Is it possible to create a chart with rich info on click function for specific country?

Tags: highcharts

I have a school project to build a map of my country. I have to make it an interactive map by showing graph when I click on the the region. I am trying to make it like this example:

https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo/rich-info

That example show the worlb map but I want the map of specific country. Are there any guidance to do this?

I have tried use that example and applied on my country map but it doesn't work. It shows a blank page.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Have a look at the map demos; https://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo several of them show how to use specific maps

Comment: Could you reproduce what you already have and how you've tried to implement it in an online code editor like jsfiddle?